# Problem getting "Programming in Scala" junit example to work in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, junit

Still learning Scala and Intellij with Scala plugin... Trying to get the SetTest class from the "Programming in Scala" 3rd edition book to work.  Here is the code that I entered into IntelliJ Idea Community 2019.3 with the latest Scala plugin:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

class SetTest {

  @Test
  def testMultiAdd = {
    val set = Set() + 1 +2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3
    assertEquals(3, set.size)
  }
}
```

I added the junit-4.3.1.jar to my project structure library via the Maven download option.  Then I click on the double green arrow in the left margin of the editor and select "Run `SetTest`".

Then I get the error "Error:(4, 7) SetTest is already defined as class SetTest
class SetTest {"

So then I delete the SetTest run configuration that IntelliJ generated.  Then I click on the single green arrow in the left marging of the editor and select "Run TestMultiAdd()".  This causes the exact same error.

I've also tried to set up different run configurations manually with no success.  Help please!

Comment: Try use sbt dependency instead of manual add library. Add it to build.sbt: `libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test`. After it, check than file name is equal to class name, and try run test again. It's work for me

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I have been using the "Idea" type of project rather than the "sbt" type.  But I set up an "sbt" type project to try out your suggestion.  Yes, it works!  I am new to Stackoverflow too but I think you need to "Answer" a post rather than "comment" on it in order to get votes, etc.  So you might do "Answer" then I can vote for it.  Thanks again.

Comment: you can accept it. Now you can't vote: it's required at least 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use sbt dependency instead of manual add library.

1. Add it to build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test.
```

2. If Intellij Idea will suggest you import changes for SBT project, then do it. Else Idea make it automatically. Also you can import it manually via command line: `sbt reload` and `sbt clean package`.
3. Check than file name is equal to class name (commonly it's not required for Scala)
4. Try run test again.

   It's work for me.

You can find this or another dependency at [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12). By default it show how to add maven dependency. But in section `SBT`
you will see line from 1st item.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Test should be named `SetTestTest` maybe then. There is already class named `SetTest`.